# How to draw an image with google app engine?

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I'd like to crate an image depending on the content of my google app engine data store, but I can't figure out how to use the google image service for doing this.

The Image has  a method "setData" but it needs a byte[] and I don't know how to build this byte[].

Answer (score 1):

I finally found this project http://code.google.com/p/pngj/ which fit perfectly my needs.